# List Boxes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I want to manually add two items as "Active" and "Inactive" in a ListBox. When the user selects "Active", i want to get the value "A" and when "Inactive" is selected, i want to get "I".

How do i do this in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .NET 4? If so, the simplest solution is probably to use `Tuple(Of String, String)`. Create a tuple of ("Active", "A") and another of ("Inactive", "I") and add those to the listbox. Then set the listbox's `DisplayMember` property to "Item1" and `ValueMember` to "Item2".

Or you could do the same sort of thing with an anonymous type.

Comment: Dear Jon, thanks for the reply. Actually, i am having an invisible listbox with data populated from a stored procedure and i have populated it by setting the DataSource. Similarly, those items, i want it to get populated into the second list box by using items.add. The requirement is that i can use the second list box for removing items by clicking a button bcaause items cannot be removed from a list box to which data is populated using DataSource. Please advice.

Comment: @George: I don't see how your extra description is relevant to the current text of your question, nor why you need an invisible listbox to start with. Please edit your question with much more context. (You haven't even said whether this is WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET etc.)

Comment: Dear Jon, am working with VB.NET [Windows Forms] and it is a desktop application. I have populated a list box using stored procedures and setting the datasource property of the list box to get the information returned from a stored procedure. No there is a button called "Delete" and when i select an item from the list box and click "Delete", the item should get deleted. I tried "ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex), but it returns an error. Now what i do is that, when the first list box gets populated, i want another one also to get populated using Items.Add, so i can delete it.

Comment: @George: You still haven't said *why* you've got this hidden listbox... and please edit all this information into the question rather than using comments.

Comment: Removing Items from a ListBox after setting the DataSource

Comment: Dear Jon, i have posted a query about the same just before this question as "Removing Items from a ListBox after setting the DataSource" and there is no reply from anyone to that question. Can you please check that and help me with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ListboxItemCollection is of type Object. You can create a custom ListItem like this

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        BindListBox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindListBox()
        With ListBox1
            .Items.Add(New CustomListItem("Acitve", "A"))
            .Items.Add(New CustomListItem("Inactive", "I"))
            .DisplayMember = "Text"
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        MsgBox(CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, CustomListItem).Value)
    End Sub

End Class


''Custom ListItem Class
Public Class CustomListItem
    Dim _text As String
    Dim _value As String

    Sub New(ByVal text As String, ByVal value As String)
        Me._text = text
        Me._value = value
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _text
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Debug.Print(ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString.Substring(0, 1))
End Sub
```